# What do I need to do to link with xlib?

Tags: c, gcc, x11, xlib

I am using GCC, what switches do I need to add to link with Xlib? After searching, all I could find was `-lX11`, but that gave me `ld: library not found for -lX11`

I am using a mac (10.6), but I would not like anything that is Mac specific.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can usually use [`pkg-config`](http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/) to determine the flags you need to pass:

```
gcc my-program.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs x11) -o my-program
```

Comment: Hey! I didn't know that was there. And I've always liked that kind of facility when individual programs supply it (e.g. `root-config` with http://root.cern.ch/).

Comment: Hmmm...mine seems to be supplied by fink (on Mac OS 10.5).

Comment: +1 : I love the answers when someone asks for a fish and gets a fishing rod in return :)

Comment: I'd like to point out that this answer didn't work for me on ubuntu (gcc 4.6.1). It places the -lX11 argument before the -o argument and since gcc searches object files and libraries in the order specified I still get 'undefined reference' errors. See also: [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

Comment: @rakete Fixed the order. The libraries need to come after the .c file, not after the -o argument, so I've left that at the end, just moved the .c file up before the library flags.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ locate libX11
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/X11R6/lib/libX11.6.2.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/X11R6/lib/libX11.6.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/X11R6/lib/libX11.a
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/X11R6/lib/libX11.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.2.0.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/X11/lib/libX11.dylib
/usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.2.0.dylib
/usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
/usr/X11/lib/libX11.dylib
/usr/X11/lib/libX11.la
```

I'd try

```
gcc [...] -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11 [...]
```

to set the search path for libraries.

Answer (score 5):

You'd be surprised, but sometimes `-L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11` **is** the answer -_-.

Answer (score 2):

You also need `-L/usr/X11/lib`. It's not exactly Mac-specific, but you will find that the location of these libs will vary a bit from system to system.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.10 (And probably others) require `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`.